# My computer shuts down randomly

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

My computer will shut down randomly when I leave it alone for a while, such as if I leave it on overnight.  It still appears to be running, the fans run and USB devices get power, but it won't respond to input from mouse/keyboard or from Remote Desktop.  I tried a magic packet, and that doesn't work either.  The only way I can restart it is to shut it down by holding the power button and restarting.  I know the problem isn't overheating, because it has happened with the side panel off.  It doesn't generate any error messages.  The strangest thing is that it only happens when I am away from it, it has never happened when I am at the computer working.  My computer specs are below.

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P
CPU: AMD FX-6300 Black Edition
RAM: 8 GB Corsair Vengeance Blue
GPU: Gigabyte AMD Radeon R9 380 GV-R938G1
HDD: WD Black 1 TB
PSU: EVGA SuperNOVA 750 G2
OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Professional (Free upgrade, not retail)

How do I solve this?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out overheating just because it has happened with the side panel off. Removing the side panel can actually have a negative effect on the performance of your cooling system. See here for more information on this: http://www.pcgamer.com/can-you-keep-your-pc-cooler-by-removing-the-side-panel/

Answer (score 0):

Check if your BIOS, OS and drivers are all up-to-date. Outdated versions may cause similar issues.

Run tools that will  check for any malware or viruses. Such malicious software could cause your system to become unresponsive.

Start the hardware tests with your storage drive to ensure data safety. Run [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=YmF51w) and see if that WD Black passes both the quick and the extended tests. If it does it should be safe to use and should cause the issue.

Try running some memory tests and see if your memory passes them.

Run stress tests and see if any of your hardware behaves abnormally under 100% load and check the temperatures while under 100% load.

Double-check all your cables if they are properly plugged all the way.

Check if your PSU deliver proper power to your parts. You can do this with a multi-meter (there are guides online on how to do this or simply take it to a technician).

Try checking the system log if you haven't and see if there's anything strange there.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails try formatting your hard drive and doing a clean install(don't forget to back up your files). Make sure to get the correct network adapter beforehand so you can automatically update the rest of your drivers by searching online. For the correct network adapter consult your motherboard